# Calculating Time in Python (datetime.timedelta?)

Tags: python, datetime

I am sure this is a nobrainer for a lot of you, but I find myself really confused with the whole datetime.timedelta thing.  Essentially I timestamp something when I start `startTime` and then I timestamp the end of the process `endTime` and I am trying to get the difference in HH:MM:SS and am having no luck.

I get this error when I do print `endTime - startTime`:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'
```

Edited to include final result:

```
startTime = datetime.now()
<... my looping process ...>
endTime = datetime.now()
calcdTime = endTime - startTime
print str(calcdTime)[:-4]
```

This outputs to: H:MM:SS.MM (thus stripping the last 4 characters off the `timedelta`

Comment: `datetime.datetime` and `datetime.date` support subtraction, but `datetime.time` does not. Try using `datetime.datetime` instead

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a `datetime` instead of a `time`. Subtracting one time from another is meaningless without a date; you can't just assume that they're on the same day and the left operand comes first.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on what you're doing with the information, you might want to just use [`time.time`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.time):

```
import time

starttime = time.time()

# do stuff

endtime = time.time()

elapsed = endtime - starttime
print elapsed
```

Which will give you the elapsed time in seconds. This is often more convenient than having a `timedelta`.