# Time difference between DateTimeProperty of Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want to know a way to find time difference in seconds between two DateTimeProperty of Google App Engine.

**Like:**

```
class Art(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    art = db.TextProperty(required=True)
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)

Art(title=title, art=art).put()
```

Now, I want to find how long ago that was it was created.

Comment: and what did you try, for example "i tried to convert them into timestamps but it failed"?

Comment: yes, it didn't work for me also.

Comment: Did you actually try this with real models, with values in the models? The code above - and the error - show that you're running this against *field property objects* on their own, which will never work.

Comment: @Balakrishnan "it didn't work for me" is completely not helpful. Show us your code, what happened, what didn't work.

Comment: It would only start to work if you have instances of the properties, in your example you have property definitions with no value .  In addition you couldn't do start-stop +'seconds' as you can not add a string to a time delta object.

Comment: Well, now this is a completely different question. What happens when you actually try this?

Comment: Seriously if you want constructive help, do the basics, and prepare a question that is consistent and illustrates what you are doing, now your edited question doesn't really do that.  As it stands this question should be closed.

Comment: I don't know a way to find difference between current time and the time it was created.

Comment: @TimHoffman Please, sorry for that. I really just want to know a solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculating Time in Python (datetime.timedelta?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061479/calculating-time-in-python-datetime-timedelta)

Comment: Hey, everyone I found the solution and thanks for your ***help***. And you can block this comment for saying thanks.

Comment: Why down-voting for no reason? This question is pretty clear & fit to stackoverflow site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting some other way as I know it..

```
import datetime    

class Art(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    art = db.TextProperty(required=True)
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
art = Art(title='title', art='art').put()
seconds = (datetime.datetime.now() - art.created).seconds

print 'Posted %s seconds ago.' % seconds
```